# How do I download an artifact from an archive in TeamCity 6.5? I can't construct the correct URL

Tags: teamcity

I have a zip archive artifact. I'm interested in downloading a single file from that artifact. I can't upload that file outside of the archive right now. The [documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts#PatternsForAccessingBuildArtifacts-ObtainingArtifacts) says you download an archive like this

```
/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_ID/BUILD_ID:id/ARTIFACT_PATH
```

So, my URL for that looks like this (and I need [anonymous access](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts#PatternsForAccessingBuildArtifacts-ObtainingArtifactsfromaBuildScript), so you see the `guest` flag). And it works!

```
/repository/download/bt23/2253:id/mypackage.zip?guest=1
```

However, I want one single file from that artifact. And the [docs are confusing](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts#PatternsForAccessingBuildArtifacts-ObtainingArtifactsfromanArchive) on how to do that. They do not specify what replaces `<zip or jar archive>`. And I am not constructing the whole `buildNumber` or `buildTypeId` values properly.

```
/repository/archive/<zip or jar archive>/buildTypeId/BUILD_TYPE_ID/buildNumber/BUILD_NUMBER/index.html
```

I tried using `zip` and `.zip'. I tried filling in the build values directly, but it's much different from the working archive download URL.

```
/repository/archive/zip/buildTypeId/bt23/buildNumber/2253/myfile.txt?guest=1
```

**Does anyone have working concrete example of the URL for a single file in an archive?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace <zip or jar archive> with relative path to your artifact. For example, if you want to retrieve file.txt from package.zip which is uploaded under dist directory in your build artifacts you need to use this url:
http://server/repository/archive/dist/package.zip/buildTypeId/bt23/buildNumber/2253/file.txt?guest=1

BTW, a new, more straightforward URL syntax will be available in TeamCity 7.0:
http://server/repository/download/bt23/2253/dist/package.zip!file.txt?guest=1

Old URLs will be supported too.